# Viewcontroller can't push to another view?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, pushviewcontroller

My problem is sample ...But I still don't know why my view won't push to another view ...

First ,I add many views in NSMutableArray

```
static NSString *titleKey = @"title";
static NSString *viewControllerKey = @"viewController";

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.menuList = [NSMutableArray array];

    FirstView *firstView = [[FirstView alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.menuList addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              NSLocalizedString(@"FirstView", @""), titleKey,
                              firstView, viewControllerKey,
                              nil]];
    [FirstView release];


    SecondView *secondView = [[SecondView alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.menuList addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              NSLocalizedString(@"SecondView", @""), titleKey,
                              secondView, viewControllerKey,
                              nil]];
    [SecondView release];
```

Ok...This how I add viewcontroller in an array ...

I want when I press the cell in the table view ,it will go to the view I want to show

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIViewController *targetViewController = [[self.menuList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:viewControllerKey];
    targetViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
}
```

After I press the cell , nothing happen

First I guess could be I didn't set the Array correctly

But When I log the array

It really something inside...

Here is the result :

```
Log message: MENU LIST (
        {
        title = "FirstView";
        viewController = "<Firstview: 0x5822500>";
    },
        {
        title = "SecondView";
        viewController = "<SecondView: 0x5822870>";
    }
)
```

I have no idea why the program won't work......

Does anyone have any ideas ???

It just a so simple thing ,still stuck here for 3 hours....

Many thanks  :)

Comment: Please show us the code that you use to allocate and initialize your navigation controller, which is essential and critical for a successful **push** action.

Comment: FirstView *firstView = [[FirstView alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];  you mean this ??

Comment: He's asking about the UINavigationController you use to push the stack onto. Where is that?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIViewController *targetViewController = [[self.menuList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:viewControllerKey];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
}

Comment: Based on the code you provide in your comment, I suspect that you didn't actually allocate your UINavigation Controller. As a result, the returning value of **[self navigationController]** is likely to be empty, your current controller cannot find a navigation controller in its parent or ancestor controller hierarchy. Therefore, any target controller won't get pushed, since no navigation controller is found to push them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check the type of `targetViewController` to see if it is giving you the correct ViewController.If it is correct,then

You really should check the `self.navigationController` value to make sure that it is not `nil`

I suspect the second thing is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well first i have to say, bravo, this is quite a challenging question.

I m and certain that my answer will help or not but just hear me out.

when you are using

`UIViewController *targetViewController = [[self.menuList objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:viewControllerKey];`

you are assigning a class of type firstview or secondview to uiviewcontroller that my be the problem.

but it is proper as a parent class can take the place of child class (assuming that the 2 class has subclassed the uiviewcontroller).

so you can place a break point on

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

and before the control reaches the end of function place your cursor on targetViewController and check what is its contents.

if it has a firstview or secondview than it will show you the type of variable the firstview and secondview is.

Comment: I dont know why this answer is voted down,this is very useful to me so im giving you an upvote

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a push action successfully you need to create a UINavigationController in your application delegate with a root view controller (root view controller = FirstView-> i hope this is a UIViewController).

After you do this, in FirstView you can call

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
```

in order to push another UIViewController on the stack.

> The UINavigationController class
>   implements a specialized view
>   controller that manages the navigation
>   of hierarchical content. This class is
>   not intended for subclassing. Instead,
>   you use instances of it as-is in
>   situations where you want your
>   application’s user interface to
>   reflect the hierarchical nature of
>   your content. This navigation
>   interface makes it possible to present
>   your data efficiently and also makes
>   it easier for the user to navigate
>   that content.

Here is the oficial link to the UINavigationController docs, they are useful.
[Link to UINavigationController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)